# Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined error in Angular Universal upgrade from 8 to 11

Tags: angular, angular-universal

When I try to upgrade Angular Universal Express Engine from 8 to 11 as part of migration.

`ng update @nguniversal/express-engine --allow-dirty --migrate-only --from 8 --to 11`

I get the following error

```
[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at _angularImportsFromNode (/project-name/node_modules/@schematics/angular/utility/ast-utils.js:179:16)
    at /project-name/node_modules/@schematics/angular/utility/ast-utils.js:222:24
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getDecoratorMetadata (/project-name/node_modules/@schematics/angular/utility/ast-utils.js:222:10)
    at /project-name/node_modules/@nguniversal/express-engine/node_modules/@nguniversal/common/schematics/migrations/update-9/index.js:160:29
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/src/rules/call.js:75:24)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:67:27)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:57:18)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at Observable._subscribe (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToArray.js:5:20)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:37:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:31)
    at MergeMapOperator.call (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:37:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:25:31)
```

I am trying to find the module which is causing this error. Browser build is working fine and server compiles without error if I ignore the migration error above.

But when I run `npm run serve:ssr`, I get

```
/project-name/dist/server.js:54108
                    const scrollToFunction = Element.prototype.scrollTo;
                                             ^

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at supportsScrollBehavior (/project-name/dist/server.js:54108:46)
    at Module.K011 (/project-name/dist/server.js:58367:55)
    at __webpack_require__ (/project-name/dist/server.js:440:35)
    at Object.0 (/project-name/dist/server.js:780:32)
    at __webpack_require__ (/project-name/dist/server.js:440:35)
    at /home/zuhair/Projects/project-name/dist/server.js:492:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project-name/dist/server.js:494:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/hproject-name/dist/server.js:245382:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (/project-name/dist/server.js:20:41)
    at Module.<anonymous> (/project-name/dist/server.js:175:16)
```

My package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/animations": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~11.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^11.1.2",
    "@thisissoon/angular-inviewport": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/chartjs": "0.0.31",
    "@types/greensock": "^1.15.32",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^8.8.1",
    "angular-csv-ext": "^1.0.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.4",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "countup.js-angular2": "^7.3.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "easy-pie-chart": "^2.1.7",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gsap": "^2.0.2",
    "helmet": "^3.16.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.5.1",
    "isotope-packery": "^2.0.1",
    "lazysizes": "^5.1.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-hijri": "^2.1.2",
    "ng-inline-svg": "8.2.1",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "git+###########@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/angular/ng-uikit-pro-standard.git#8.10.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.2.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^8.0.8",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.2.0",
    "ngx-scrollreveal": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.1.1",
    "screenfull": "^3.3.0",
    "scrollmagic": "^2.0.6",
    "secure-web-storage": "^1.0.2",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.9",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^11.0.0",
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1101.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~11.1.1",
    "@nguniversal/common": "^11.1.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.47",
    "@types/moment-hijri": "^2.1.0",
    "angular-user-idle": "^2.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "cypress": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "karma": "~5.2.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-jasmine-rules": "^1.6.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "browser": {
    "crypto": false
  }
```

My environment:-

```
Angular CLI: 11.1.2
Node: 12.20.1
OS: linux x64

Angular: 11.1.1
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, material
... material-moment-adapter, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                                    Version
--------------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect                  0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular              0.1101.2
@angular-devkit/core                       11.1.2
@angular-devkit/schematics                 11.1.2
@angular/cli                               11.1.2
@nguniversal/common                        11.1.1
@nguniversal/express-engine                11.1.1
@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader   8.2.6
@schematics/angular                        11.1.2
@schematics/update                         0.1101.2
rxjs                                       6.5.4
typescript                                 4.0.5
```

How can I debug this? Is there any flag to give more data about where the error is coming from in Angular Universal? Will add more data, if more clarity is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Element definition from the 'domino' package solved the problem in Angular SSR mode for me:

```
  global['Element'] = (domino as any).impl.Element;
```